# Can't insert data to Database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, netbeans

Can't make basic things. The connection to database is good, cause it shows list, deletes data lines. Also after submiting, it doesn't show any errors, but it doesn't show in database...I am still a beginner in PHP, I searched thoroughly but I can't find out what's wrong in code

This is my model class:

```
    <?php

class abonimentas {

        private $abonimentas_lentele = '';

        public function __construct() {
        $this->abonimentas_lentele = config::DB_PREFIX . 'abonimentas';

    }



        public function getAbonimentasListCount() {
        $query = "  SELECT COUNT(`{$this->abonimentas_lentele}`.`id`) as `kiekis`
                    FROM `{$this->abonimentas_lentele}`";
        $data = mysql::select($query);

        return $data[0]['kiekis'];
    }

        public function getAbonimentas($id) {
        $query = "  SELECT *
                    FROM `{$this->abonimentas_lentele}`
                    WHERE `id`='{$id}'";
        $data = mysql::select($query);

        return $data[0];
    }

        public function insertAbonimentas($data) {
        $query = "  INSERT INTO `abonimentas`
                                (
                                    `pavadinimas`,
                                    `aprasymas`,
                                                                        `papildomos_salygos`,
                                                                        `kaina`
                                )
                                VALUES
                                (
                                    '{$data['pavadinimas']}',
                                    '{$data['aprasymas']}',
                                                                        '{$data['papildomos_salygos']}'
                                                                        '{$data['kaina']}'
                                )";
        mysql::query($query);

        return mysql::getLastInsertedId();
    }

        public function updateAbonimentas($data) {
        $query = "  UPDATE `abonimentas`
                    SET     `pavadinimas`='{$data['pavadinimas']}',
                        `aprasymas`='{$data['aprasymas']}',
                                                `papildomos_salygos`='{$data['papildomos_salygos']}',
                                                `kaina`='{$data['kaina']}'
                    WHERE `id`='{$data['id']}'";
        mysql::query($query);
    }

}
```

This is creation class:

```
<?php

include 'libraries/abonimentas.class.php';
$abonimentasObj = new abonimentas();

$formErrors = null;
$data = array();

$required = array('pavadinimas', 'aprasymas', 'papildomos_salygos', 'kaina');

$maxLengths = array (
    'pavadinimas' => 40,
    'aprasymas' => 200,
        'papildomos_salygos' => 200
);

if(!empty($_POST['submit'])) {
    // nustatome laukų validatorių tipus
    $validations = array (
        'pavadinimas' => 'anything',
        'aprasymas' => 'anything',
                'papildomos_salygos' => 'anything',
        'kaina' => 'price');

    include 'utils/validator.class.php';
    $validator = new validator($validations, $required, $maxLengths);

    if($validator->validate($_POST)) {
        $dataPrepared = $validator->preparePostFieldsForSQL();
        $dataPrepared['id'] = $abonimentasObj->insertAbonimentas($dataPrepared);

        $abonimentasObj->updateAbonimentas($dataPrepared);

        header("Location: index.php?module={$module}&action=list");
        die();
    } else {

        $formErrors = $validator->getErrorHTML();

        $data = $_POST;
    }
} 

include 'templates/abonimentas_form.tpl.php';

?>
```

This is template for input:

```
 <ul id="pagePath">
    <li><a href="index.php">Pradžia</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?module=<?php echo $module; ?>&action=list">Abonimentai</a></li>
    <li><?php if(!empty($id)) echo "Abonimento redagavimas"; else echo "Naujas abonimentas"; ?></li>
</ul>
<div class="float-clear"></div>
<div id="formContainer">
    <?php if($formErrors != null) { ?>
        <div class="errorBox">
            Neįvesti arba neteisingai įvesti šie laukai:
            <?php 
                echo $formErrors;
            ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Abonimento informacija</legend>
            <p>
                <label class="field" for="pavadinimas">Pavadinimas<?php echo in_array('pavadinimas', $required) ? '<span> *</span>' : ''; ?></label>
                <input type="text" id="pavadinimas" name="pavadinimas" class="textbox textbox-200" value="<?php echo isset($data['pavadinimas']) ? $data['pavadinimas'] : ''; ?>">
                <?php if(key_exists('pavadinimas', $maxLengths)) echo "<span class='max-len'>(iki {$maxLengths['pavadinimas']} simb.)</span>"; ?>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label class="field" for="aprasymas">Aprašymas<?php echo in_array('aprasymas', $required) ? '<span> *</span>' : ''; ?></label>
                <textarea id="aprasymas" name="aprasymas" class=""><?php echo isset($data['aprasymas']) ? $data['aprasymas'] : ''; ?></textarea>
                <?php if(key_exists('aprasymas', $maxLengths)) echo "<span class='max-len'>(iki {$maxLengths['aprasymas']} simb.)</span>"; ?>
            </p>
                        <p>
                <label class="field" for="papildomos_salygos">Papildomos sąlygos<?php echo in_array('papildomos_salygos', $required) ? '<span> *</span>' : ''; ?></label>
                <textarea id="papildomos_salygos" name="papildomos_salygos" class=""><?php echo isset($data['papildomos_salygos']) ? $data['papildomos_salygos'] : ''; ?></textarea>
                <?php if(key_exists('papildomos_salygos', $maxLengths)) echo "<span class='max-len'>(iki {$maxLengths['papildomos_salygos']} simb.)</span>"; ?>
            </p>
                        <p>
                <label class="field" for="kaina">Kaina<?php echo in_array('kaina', $required) ? '<span> *</span>' : ''; ?></label>
                                <input type="number" id="kaina" name="kaina" class=""><?php echo isset($data['kaina']) ? $data['kaina'] : ''; ?></input>
                <?php if(key_exists('kaina', $maxLengths)) echo "<span class='max-len'>(iki {$maxLengths['kaina']} simb.)</span>"; ?>
            </p>
        </fieldset>

        <p class="required-note">* pažymėtus laukus užpildyti privaloma</p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" class="submit button" name="submit" value="Išsaugoti">
        </p>
        <?php if(isset($data['id'])) { ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $data['id']; ?>" />
        <?php } ?>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you make a connection to the database anywhere? I cannot see one

Comment: Your insert statement's values clause seems to be missing a comma between values..